# SQL how to know the datatype for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I'm using MS Access and MS Sql 2008, I need get the DataType for a specific column in a single table.

Could you please post a sample of code?

Comment: Is Google down for you? http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/04/27/60574.aspx

Comment: Thanks Ic unfortunately I was not able to find a solution, I need smt very simple I'm a really beginner thanks for your comment

Comment: Are you trying to get info from Access or SQL Server?  Also, is this an ad-hoc, one-time job, or do you need to program this?

Comment: I'm trying to get this from Access using odbc to an Oracle DataBase, it is just one-time job.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use catalog views:

```
SELECT  sch.name [Schema],
        tbl.name [Table],
        col.name [Column],
        typ.name [Type]
FROM    sys.columns col
JOIN    sys.tables tbl ON 
        tbl.object_id = col.object_id
AND     tbl.name = 'tableName'
JOIN    sys.schemas sch ON
        sch.schema_id = tbl.schema_id
AND     sch.name = 'schemaName'
JOIN    sys.types typ ON
        typ.system_type_id = col.system_type_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to programmatically get schema metadata for your **MS Access DB**, as there are other answers for SQL Server.  Unfortunately, MS Access doesn't offer an `information_schema` catalog of views (or any real analog) to query directly, so you might have to try one of the following:

- Create a linked server in SQL Server to your Access DB, and [query through that](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Microsoft-Access/Configuring-a-Linked-Microsoft-Access-Server-on-SQL-2005-Server/).
- Use something like [`GetOleDbSchemaTable`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309488) in your app.